# How see all non threadsafe plugins in maven?

Tags: java, maven, parallel-builds

I have read about maven parallel build configuration in [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3). So how I can display all non thread safe plugins? Is there something like "plugin-not-safe-list" command in maven?

```
REM something like that to display all p[lugins without @threadSafe  annotation
mvn help:plugin-not-safe-list
```

Answer (score 4):

Now when you build Maven warns about plugins not marked as threadsafe:

```
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *
[WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that have goals not marked   *
[WARNING] * as @threadSafe to support parallel building.                  *
[WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *
[WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *
[WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *
[WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in Root Maven Parent:
[WARNING] com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.3.0
[WARNING] Enable debug to see more precisely which goals are not marked @threadSafe.
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom rule for [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) and use it for running on your maven project.

You might also want to use the [mojo-executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) to parse the `plugin.xml` file for checking its "thread safe" property.

A little elaboration on when and why you should use the above.
When you are working in CI/CD environment, and you want to employ the parallel compilation via maven, you should constantly monitor that your developers are not adding non-thread safe plugins, in order to ensure the consistency and correctness of the CI/CD. In order to achieve that, you can use the above mentioned *maven-envorcer-plugin* with custom rule. Your custom rule can use the Maven Plugin API (maven project, etc.) in order to search all the plugins in the projects, and then use the *mojo-executor* lib in order to read the `threadSafe` property of each plugin (since the maven API does not provide that). *mojo-executor* lib has tools to parse the `plugin.xml` file of a maven plugin where the `threadSafe` property resides.
Once found, you can fail the maven build.

If you want to see only the list of the non-thread safe plugins, you can use the same technique, and just list the plugins which `threadSafe` property is false.
You can then configure the `maven-enforcer-plugin` to use the custom rule (for example, a profile of the project), and run it via command line in a single maven command.

BTW, what happens when you find a non-thread safe plugin in your development project, and there are no thread safe alternatives, is another question, which is also solvable.

Comment: "BTW, what happens when you find a non-thread safe plugin in your development project, and there are no thread safe alternatives, is another question, which is also solvable." could you help to give a detailed explanation how to solve this?

Comment: The solution is pretty straight forward, not sure why there is no open source for that yet. I wrote such for my previous employer. You should write a new wrapper plugin, which has a semaphore for not allowing more than one execution in parallel of the same plugin identified by {groupId}+{artifactId}. Since maven executes all the plugins in the same process but different threads in parallel - simple global semaphore should do the trick (singleton). Then for each non-thread safe plugin, you define it via the wrapper plugin

Comment: One can say that, it is not real parallelism, if the same plugin will run serially and not in parallel. My tests shown, that on a big enterprise project it is still better than the alternative of running all the build serially. The improvement was 40% less build time with 3 threads. There is a limit on how many threads will give benefit the bulld time, depending on the complexity of the local inter-dependency of the modules in the project